# Azure Api For Virtual Machine

Tags: api, azure

Is there an Azure api which provide the list of all virtual machines types and specify whether the machine is general purpose, memory optimized or storage optimized?

Comment: `virtual machines types` do you mean VM size, such as A0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query this endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get

It will give you all the data about vm. You won't get memory\storage\compute optimized, but you can infer this from the VM size.

Comment: Actually their pricing documentations categories the each vm to some category [like general , compute optimize].I am using azure usage API and get the vm [like A0,A1] under subcategory so , I am not able to  group vm by category[like compute optimize].

Comment: there is no such api as azure doesnt have those categories (they are there only for you human convenience)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is this public API you can use also:
https://azure.microsoft.com/api/v2/pricing/virtual-machines-base/calculator/?culture=en-us&discount=mosp

In the section "Offers", you will get the spec you are looking for:

```
"windows-a0-basic": {
        "cores": 1,
        "ram": 0.75,
        "diskSize": 20,
        "series": "A",
...
```